# Can't block html5 video element using javascript

Tags: youtube, greasemonkey, html5-video

Youtube has recently began playing html5 webm version of videos on some pages even though flash is available in your browser and you are not in html5 trial.

For example these videos play html5 webm by default:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuU91TU7O3s

Other examples
    (watch?v=Z3IGfwcGBP8)
    (watch?v=kYcNJQ3Y6Sg)
    (watch?v=c6tEKLT5G2M)

I am trying to block video elements using greasemonkey javascript. For most youtube videos just removing the video element works. For example:

```
var h5video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
h5video.parentNode.removeChild(h5video)
```

But on this specific page, the video still plays even though you removed the video element, you will hear the audio.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCn-rmgECY0

Why is the video still playing?

How can you block the video using javascript? I want the script to actually break or block the video from loading not just somehow pausing/stopping the video.

Comment: the pause button only pauses the video in your link.
The audio is still played, and echoed.
I think the page is playing the html5 and the flash video at same time.

Here is your video, but in flash: http://www.youtube.com/v/CuU91TU7O3s

Comment: I wandering why you want to block the video so much

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to remove the `video`, `audio`, `embed`, and `object` elements:

```
try {
    var h5video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
    h5video.parentNode.removeChild(h5video);

    var h5audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    h5audio.parentNode.removeChild(h5audio);

    var object = document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];
    object.parentNode.removeChild(object);

    var embed = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0];
    embed.parentNode.removeChild(embed);
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

**References**

- [MDN: HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)
- [Simplified Adaptive Video Streaming: Announcing support for HLS and DASH in Windows 10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/01/29/simplified-adaptive-video-streaming-announcing-support-for-hls-and-dash-in-windows-10.aspx)
- [Acceptance of Media Source Extensions as W3C Candidate Recommendation will accelerate adoption of dash.js](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2014/01/09/acceptance-of-media-source-extensions-as-w3c-candidate-recommendation-will-accelerate-adoption-of-dash-js.aspx)
- [[MS-HTML5E]: Microsoft Edge / Internet Explorer Extensions to the HTML5 Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn705441)